# PHP calls '>' unknown modifer in regular expression? ( Delimiter issue )

Tags: php, pcre

```
private function pageScrape( $url )
{
    $page_stream = file_get_contents( $url );
    $pattern = '/<link\s+(?=[^>]*rel="(?:[Ss]hortcut\s)?[Ii]con"\s+)(?:[^>]*href="(.+?)").*/>/';
    preg_match( $pattern, $page_stream, $matches );
    print_r( $matches );
    // echo $page_stream;
}
```

gives error:

> **Warning**:  preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier
>   '>' in
>   **/home/foo/public_html/foo/source/class.ControlBookmark.php**
>   on line **16**

PHP.net reference on pcre

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex boundaries/delimiter in your regex pattern variable `$pattern` like this:

```
$pattern = '#<link\s+(?=[^>]*rel="(?:[Ss]hortcut\s)?[Ii]con"\s+)(?:[^>]*href="(.+?)").*/>#';
```

Comment: I like forward slashes for  consistency.

Comment: Since your regex already has / (forward slash) it is better to avoid using / as regex delimiter (like in my answer using #) or else escape it like this \/.

Comment: In PCRE regex you can use any of these: `/` or `#` or `~` or `|` or `@` or `;` as regex delimiter.

Comment: ...wow..that would explain a lot...I saw someone use ~...and I didn't know what the heck it was....I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Make not that ~ looks the coolest I think...like a regular expression angel with wings...

Answer (score 1):

You problem is due to unescaped slash at the end of your expression.  Try this instead:

```
$pattern = '/<link\s+(?=[^>]*rel="(?:[Ss]hortcut\s)?[Ii]con"\s+)(?:[^>]*href="(.+?)").*\/>/';
```